Why did SpaceX B1062 have a landing failure?
On August 28, 2024, after 267 consecutive successful landings, the Falcon 9 booster experienced a failed landing. A landing leg appears to have visibly failed during the landing, causing the booster to fall. According to the telemetry, the boosters speed never seems to reach 0, is that the cause of the failure? This was the boosters 23rd launch, was SpaceX’s most used booster, and therefore it has landed successfully many times. What went wrong and why didn’t this occur on earlier flights of the booster?

Scott Manly suggests fatigue in the composite landing leg. youtube.com/watch?v=QJjRpeO5FXs   Cyclic loading contributes to fatigue failure which could be why it “didn’t occur on earlier flights of the booster?”sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2238785422017598

Would you please stop asking questions about failures shortly after they happen? Please! It takes weeks, sometimes years, to resolve such questions, and by then the answer is all over the news and the internet.

@DavidHammen: While I agree with you, and other aerospace related SE sites do as well (for example, on [aviation.se], it is explicitly forbidden to ask about incidents before the official report is published, and such questions get summarily downvoted, closed, and deleted in quick succession), on this site, these questions are allowed … even if there is no point in asking them, since they are not answerable. There are examples of questions that have been sitting there, and then been answered two years later when the report came out.

FWIW, Scott suggests that the telemetry never hitting zero may just be a signal glitch caused by the impact or downstream results of it rather than evidence that the booster hit hard. The telemetry isn't really well synced to the video image.
